# Replace row values to the left of a row-specific column-index value in the same row

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, replace

A data table shows status reports for projects by years of life:

```
def <- data.frame(c("ProjA", "ProjB", "ProjC"), c("0", "2", "2"), 
              c("Active", "Cancelled", "Distressed"), c("Active", NA, "Distressed"), 
              c("Active", "Cancelled", "Distressed"), c("Active", NA, "Distressed"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(def) <- c("proj.name", "status.update.year", "year.0", "year.1", "year.2", "year.3")
def$status.update.year <- as.numeric(def$status.update.year)

def

  proj.name status.update.year     year.0     year.1     year.2     year.3
1     ProjA                  0     Active     Active     Active     Active
2     ProjB                  2  Cancelled       <NA>  Cancelled       <NA>
3     ProjC                  2 Distressed Distressed Distressed Distressed
```

`status.update.year` variable records year of change from `"Active"` to another status.

Projects  should begin `"Active"` but a project which became `"Distressed"` in year 3 is now reported to be `"Distressed"` in all past years for which there is an observation. This erroneous back-dating is what I want to correct.

I want to change the row values for columns labelled "0" to "3", such that before the year of status update, all non-NA observations are marked "Active" before the year of status change, with a result like this:

```
  proj.name status.update.year     year.0     year.1     year.2     year.3
1     ProjA                  0     Active     Active     Active     Active
2     ProjB                  2     Active       <NA>  Cancelled       <NA>
3     ProjC                  2     Active     Active Distressed Distressed
```

I can find all non-NA observations for each row ***before*** the last non-NA observation:

```
apply(def[ ,3:6], 1, function(x) { head(x[!is.na(x)], -1) })
```

How to replace these values with `"Active"` when they are before each row-specific `status.update.year`?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to convert all cases where the year is <= `status.update.year` to `Active` except where there's an NA?

Comment: Yes exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
def = data.table(def)

for (y in 0:3) {
  v = paste0('year.',y)
  def[!is.na(get(v)) & y < status.update.year, (v):= 'Active']
}
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `set` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(def)
for(j in 0:3) {
  j1 <- grep(j, names(def))
  set(def, i = which(!is.na(def[[j1]]) & j < def$status.update.year),
                                   j = j1, value = "Active")
 }
```